# why does spring security oauth2 authorization server keep calling UserDetailsService?

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

Get access token through password grant type, why does authorization server keep calling UserDetailsService when user password is wrong

```
2021-01-19 20:41:29.801 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2021-01-19 20:41:29.801 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2021-01-19 20:41:29.801 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2021-01-19 20:41:29.807 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/oauth/token", parameters={masked}
2021-01-19 20:41:29.817 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint#postAccessToken(Principal, Map)
2021-01-19 20:41:30.292 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
2021-01-19 20:41:30.297 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2021-01-19 20:41:30.297 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2021-01-19 20:41:30.302 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2021-01-19 20:41:30.306 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2021-01-19 20:41:30.425 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
2021-01-19 20:41:30.425 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2021-01-19 20:41:30.426 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2021-01-19 20:41:30.431 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2021-01-19 20:41:30.435 DEBUG 38781 --- [nio-9007-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
```

Hope is to prompt that the password is wrong.

My UserDetailsService is:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userMapper.selectByUserName(username);
        User userRoles = userMapper.selectRolesById(user.getId());
        List<String> roles = userRoles.getRoles().stream().map(Role::getRole).collect(Collectors.toList());
        User userResourcePermissions = userMapper.selectResourcePermissionsById(user.getId());
        List<String> resourcePermissions = userResourcePermissions.getResourcePermissions().stream()
                .map(roleResourcePermissionRef -> String.format("%s:%s",roleResourcePermissionRef.getResourceCode(),roleResourcePermissionRef.getPermissionCode()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        resourcePermissions.add("a1");
        UserDetails userDetails = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername(user.getUserName())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .roles(roles.toArray(new String[0]))
                .authorities(resourcePermissions.toArray(new String[0]))
                .build();
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
//                 .and().parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
        ;
    }
}
```

Caused by the `.and().parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())` .

Answer (score 0):

Because it has to get the user details in order to check the password.

```java
if (!this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
    this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value");
    throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages
            .getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
}
```

[o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:76](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.4.2/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java#L76)

Comment: But it needs to fetch the user details in order to know that it is wrong

Comment: Is that reasonable

Comment: Not use o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider ,user the `org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider`

Comment: That doesn't check any passwords

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227562/discussion-between-jast-and-orangedog).